# I don't understand the (very simple) mathematics behind this (broader topic = lambdas/functions)

Tags: python, math

this is the topic matter that is the context of my question:

```
#named function
def polynomial(x):
    return x**2 + 5*x + 4
print(polynomial(-4))

#lambda
print((lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4) (-4))
```

Now, the answer to this is 0 and I could just continue if I wanted, but I always want to understand the mathematics behind these things. When I do this simple calculation, my answer is -32 and not 0. I have written down a bunch of things in Pycharm:

```
print((-4) ** 2 + (-4) * 5 +4)
print(-4 ** 2 + -4 * 5 +4)
print((lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4) (-4))
print(4 ** 2 + 4 * 5 +4)
print((4 ** 2) + (4 * 5) +4)
print(-16 + -20)
print((-16) + (-20))
print((-16 - -20 ) - 4 )
```

based on the following topic (just the reply): https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/376196/named-function-def-polynomial-x-return-x-2-5-x-4-print-polynomial-4-lambda-print-lambda-x-x-2-5-x-4

and the answers are:

```
0
-32
0
40
40
-36
-36
0
```

**In summary: I don't understand what happens exactly because the argument is a negative value mathematics-wise. Again, the Python just does the job for me but I want to understand what happens because I cannot reproduce it, and when I try it on my own I get -32 as an answer, because in my manual calculation, it would be (-4 tothepowerof 2 = -16)  +  (5 * -4 = -20) + 4 = -32**

Comment: `-4**2` means `-(4**2)`, it is not the same as `(-4)**2`. Python is correct and you are wrong. Your question says you cannot reproduce what Python is doing, but your first test `print((-4) ** 2 + (-4) * 5 +4)` does reproduce it with a correct result of 0.

Comment: This is really a math question: your "(-4 tothepowerof 2 = -16)" is incorrect, if you mean (-4) to the power of (2), which is (-4)*(-4) = +16. This is different from (-(4 to the power of 2)) = -16. In the code, it all depends on the [order of precedence of operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I was kinda suspecting this but I cannot ''reproduce'' it in the sense that I don't understand it mentally, of course Python is right, it's just that I didn't know about what you write in your first sentence, and I do not understand it either. Is it because ** has preference over - ?

Comment: "Is it because ** has preference over - ? " Yes, that is exactly correct. Exponentiation (**) has precedence, i.e. is combined first with its two arguments; the negation comes last. When you pass -4 to a function, it is already a negative number so you get a different result.

Comment: @ user202729 Thanks for the link, it helps clarify the problem, which is essentially a problem of precedence, but:

@alexis I think I don't understand the last phrase, and I also don't understand how you would do a calculation like print((lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4) (-4)) with the other outcome meaning that the - takes preference over the ** or *. Sorry if it sounds overly complicated but I can imagine that you would also want to use a function to calculate something based on a negative value that is more important than a calculation like exponentiation, and thus needs to have precedence.

Comment: If you pass -4 to your function, you will square the -4. You are not passing the number and the sign separately. It is only when Python (or a human reader) parses the sequence of symbols `-`, `4`, `**`, `2` that precedence can come into play.